# Sublime text 2, how to set hotkey to menu items 'View - Word Wrap Column - etc'?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

I've found solutions on hotkeys `Edit - Wrap - etc` menu, and `View - Word Wrap` toggle. But not `View - Word Wrap Column - etc` menu items. Also tried to find plugins, nothing ...

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/key_bindings.html

> Currently there is no compiled list of all built-in commands. The
> names of many commands can be found by looking at the `Default ({PLATFORM_NAME}).sublime-keymap` files in the `Default/` package.

Comment: Why are you still using ST2? It's obselete! Upgrade, my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and enter

```py
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

it will print the command for *every. single. thing. you. do.* Change the `True` to `False` to turn it off.

At any rate, for **`View → Word Wrap Column → 80`**, for example, it prints

```
command: set_setting {"setting": "wrap_width", "value": 80}
```

To set the keyboard shortcut, open your `.sublime-keymap` file and add the following:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+8"], 
  "command": "set_setting", 
  "args": {"setting": "wrap_width", "value": 80} 
}
```

You can of course change the `keys` to whatever you want.

Comment: Excuse me, but `wrap_width` is a (how to say it).. "settings function", not hotkey syntax. It must be set once and for all in `Preferences - Settings - Default` file, not `Preferences - Key Bindings - User`.

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-make-word-wrap-column-automatic-always-automatically/19027

Comment: @sasha111000 the command is `set_setting`, not `wrap_width`. Please see the addition to my answer.

Comment: It's working now, I'd just tinkered with key binding syntax. Thank you very much.